# Expresion regular fecha en solaris

Tags: unix, línea-de-comandos

Necesito encontrar archivos que su extensión termine con una fecha formato `YYYYMMDD`, en Linux tengo el siguiente comando:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex './.*.([0-9]{4})(0[1-9]|1[012])([12][0-9]|[0-9]|3[01]){2}'
```

Pero en Solaris no sirve, e intentado de distintas forma pero siempre finaliza en error.

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y mostrar el error sera mas facil ayudarte así

Answer (score 1):

Estás muy cerca, sólo faltan unos retoques en la expresión regular:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\..*[0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'
```

Descripción:

```
.*\..*[0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

- `.*` ::: cualquier cantidad de caracteres desde el inicio
- `\.` ::: un punto literal (tiene que ir escapado con la barra, de lo contrario coincide con cualquier caracter)
- `.*` ::: cualquier cantidad de caracteres desde el punto en adelante
- `[0-9]{4}` ::: 4 dígitos (año)
- `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])` ::: un cero seguido de 1 a 9, **o** un 1 seguido de 0 a 2 (mes)
- `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` ::: 0 seguido de 1 a 9, **o** 1 o 2 seguido de 0 a 9, **o** un 3 seguido de un 0 o 1 (día)

Alternativamente, quizás no quieras complicarte con tanta validación, y sólo busques un archivo terminado en 8 dígitos:

```
.*[0-9]{8}
```